Converting a string representation of an hex number into a binary string (in postgres)?
How can I convert a single hex character into a binary string (i.e. a set of ones and zeros)
Given "0" return "0000" 
Given "1" return "0001" 
Given "2" return "0010" 
... 
Given "f" return "1111"

I can get something crude working with a simple CASE statement, but was hoping for something a little more elegant.

You can prepend a literal 'x' to make it a hexadecimal constant of a bit string, then cast that to bit(4): demo at dB<>fiddle
create function hex_char_to_bit(text)
returns text return ('x'||$1)::bit(4)::text;

select hex_char_to_bit('f');




hex_char_to_bit




1111



